how to open user default browser from twa application?
I have a Trusted Web Activity (TWA) application, and users can make purchases through it.
The problem is that the payment page should open in the user's default browser, not inside the TWA app.
However, none of the methods I've tried work, and the page still opens inside the TWA app.
i tried below codes:

window.open(redirect_url);

window.location.href =
intent://${redirect_url}/#Intent;scheme=https;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;end;`

window.location.href =
intent://${redirect_url}/#Intent;scheme=https;end;`


but none of them work and the page opened inside of my twa app.
also i should mention that i open the website in telegram app and from there  my browser got open but when i test on my twa application it not work.
is there a way to solve this issue?
